# ora 00979: not a group by expression

Tags: sql, oracle8i, ora-00979

In Oracle 8i I want the single value of `trntotamt` having `max(trndt)` by grouping of `trnmemenrolno`.

I am trying with following sql query, but its giving error- ora 00979: not a group by expression

When I add the all columns specified in `SELECT` statement than its getting many records with single `trnmemenrolno`. Pls suggest what to do....

```
SELECT TRNMEMENROLNO, MAX(TRNDT),TRNTOTAMT 
FROM TRNSAC1 
WHERE TRNTYPE='R' 
GROUP BY TRNMEMENROLNO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TRNMEMENROLNO, TRNDT,TRNTOTAMT 
FROM TRNSAC1 
WHERE TRNTYPE='R' 
AND (TRNMEMENROLNO, TRNDT) IN 
( SELECT TRNMEMENROLNO, MAX(TRNDT)
  FROM TRNSAC1 
  WHERE TRNTYPE='R' 
  GROUP BY TRNMEMENROLNO
)
```